# Render PDF using PDF.JS and AngularJS from byte array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf.js

I've been following the following links to try to render a byte stream returned from an API to a PDF in browser using PDF.JS:

- http://codingcrazy87.blogspot.com/2014/05/view-pdf-files-directly-within-browser.html
- https://gist.github.com/fcingolani/3300351

Here is the **JavaScript** used to run render. **Note:** *stream* is a byte array returned from an API.

```
var file = new Blob([stream], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
$scope.renderPDF(fileURL, document.getElementById('pdf-holder'));
```

Here is **$scope.renderPDF**:

```
$scope.renderPDF = function(url, canvasContainer) {
    var scale= 1.5;  //"zoom" factor for the PDF

    function renderPage(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        page.render(renderContext);
    }

    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }

    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);

}
```

Here is the **HTML** in my template page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>

<div id="pdf-holder">
</div>
```

When the code runs

```
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
```

I get a 404 Not Found error on *worker.js*, which makes sense because I'm following these examples and disabling worker so I shouldn't need it. Does anyone have any advice or an easy way around this that I can render a pdf in browser from a byte stream?

Comment: By disabling worker you just disabling loading PDF parser code using Web Worker to make legacy browsers work. The parser code still needs to be loaded, in your case it will be loaded via script tag; you still need to set 'workerSrc'

Comment: That works. I'm now getting the error "Unhandled promise rejection" so the getDocument(url) is failing. My url is = blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/56cfc1c4-cd80-4284-af8b-a0bdecc163e9 Is there anything obvious that will make this fail?

Comment: PDF.js files are not located at your localhost? Try to make it work with files located on one server first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need pdf.worker.js even if you have disabled it. Disabling it means that PDFJS will use faked workers for which it is also using the worker library. Just set it in the following way:

```
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
```

Comment: That works.

I'm now getting the error "Unhandled promise rejection" so the getDocument(url) is failing. 

My url is = blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/56cfc1c4-cd80-4284-af8b-a0bdecc163e9

Is there anything obvious that will make this fail?